# How to compare two arrays and eliminate duplicates python

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I'm trying to get clean values, remove duplicate values, and associate correctly this two arrays:

What i have:

| soid | cid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | e |
| 4 | f |

```
soid = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
cid = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

The result has to be like this:

| soid | cid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a // b |
| 2 | c // d |
| 3 | e |
| 4 | f |

```
soid = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
cid = [ "a // b", "c // d", "e", "f"]
```

The input is not sorted.
The order of the columns relation is very important.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby` from the standard library

Comment: 1) Are the input arrays sorted ? 2) Is the order of elements in either of arrays important?

Comment: @the23Effect  the input is not sorted. The order is very important Thank you

Comment: Can you please edit this post to include these two details so that others can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, this should satisfy your requirements,

**For (Python < 3.7)** you need to use OrderedDict,

```
from collections import OrderedDict

combiner = OrderedDict()
for x, y in zip(soid, cid):
    combiner.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

soid = combiner.keys()
cid = [ r" // ".join(x) for x in combiner.values()]
```

**For (Python >= 3.7)** you can simply do this:

```
combiner = dict()
for x, y in zip(soid, cid):
    combiner.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

soid = combiner.keys()
cid = [ r" // ".join(x) for x in combiner.values()]
```

This may be faster than the above method, haven't tested yet,

```
from collections import defaultdict

combiner = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for x, y in zip(soid, cid):
    combiner[x].append(y)

soid = combiner.keys()
cid = [ r" // ".join(x) for x in combiner.values()]
```

**Note:**
From Python 3.7 onwards, the normal dict maintains the order of insertion of keys like the OrderedDict.

The keys will maintain insertion order(as it's an OrderedDict), and so will the values (as it's a list).

Comment: This is also an O(n+k) solution as there is no sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools # itertools has many useful functions for working with streams

combined = zip(soid, cid) # Combine them into one collection
result = []
for group, items in itertools.groupby(combined), lambda i: i[0]): #Group them by the first value
    result.append((group, '//'.join(i[1] for i in items))) # Add the result to result

soid = [i[0] for i in result] # Optional: Split the result back into separate lists
cid = [i[1] for i in result]
```

If the result is not sorted you can use `combined = sorted(combined, key=lambda i: i[0])`. If you don't only adjacent items in the same group will be joined.

If the order is very important, you can use this instead: `combined = sorted(combined, key=lambda i: soid.index(i[0]))` This will order groups by the index of the first element of `soid` that shares the key.

Comment: Input array is not sorted groupby() won't work.

Comment: Wait for him to answer my second question, if you sort the array you will lose the order on the output(Though they are grouped each element may still retain the insertion order atleast among its own group)

Comment: Hi, what i am getting is 

[1,2,3,4] 
["a // b", "c // d", "e", "f"] 
[]
[]

I'm looking why this two empty arrays are showing, but this is what I need, I have just only adjust my code so I can implemented OK . Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexHernan I'm not sure why 2 extra arrays are printing for you, I only generate 2. Please consider clicking the green check-mark if this answered your question.